# Find out the angle in a circle based on temperature

Tags: circles, angle

I have a specific range of temperature from a circle control which I'm developing for mobiles. This control has a range of temperatures from 35.0C to 41.5C. I would like to know how can I discover the specific angle passing a value inside this range, for example: 38.0C.
My math skills are poor. I admit.

Comment: Is it fair to assume that your control is linear (and accurate) in the angle? For instance, is it not the case that the first half of the knob changes the temperature at a greater rate? Also, do you want a solution with a specific "0". The mathematical convention would be to put 35.0C on the right and have temperature increase with counterclockwise rotation. However I think most people are more used to the convention of 35.0C on the left and temperature increasing as you rotate clockwise.

Comment: My control is linear, and  it increases at clockwise rotation. And yes, 35.0C is on the right. My control is just a full circle with a thumb in which the user touches it to modify and after the change it needs to retain the selected angle.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @JeremyUpsal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your control looks a bit like a speedometer, rather than a full circle, you just need to interpolate the desired angle into the range between start angle $a$  and end angle $b$, knowing that the start angle corresponds to $35.0°$C and the end angle corresponds to $41.5°$C

So for a temperature $T$, $\frac{\large T-35}{\large 41.5-35}$ gives the proportion of how far through the range it is, and $a + (b-a)\times \frac{\large T-35}{\large 41.5-35}$ gives the relevant angle by scaling the temperautre range to the angle range.

Comment: It's a full circle my control